# Launch an app that doesn't have main window in Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

As explained at [this site](http://www.xmldatabases.org/WK/blog/1154%5FHandling%5FURL%5Fschemes%5Fin%5FCocoa.item), I could  launch an app from Safari.

I need to  open an app that does some work behind the curtain, so I want an app that doesn't have a main window.

- Q : How can I make an app that doesn't have a main window or that doesn't show any window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is to remove the window from the nib/xib file. If you want to additionally not have a dock icon, set the `Application is agent (UIElement)` key in the info.plist to true

Comment: Could you elaborate the answer a little bit more? I could open the UIBuilder, and found 'Window' at MainMenu.nib. But, I don't know how to delete it.

Comment: And, for the 'Application is agent (UIElement) key', I can't find it. Is it just OK to add the key 'Application is agent', and make it true in the info.plist?

Comment: @prosseek for the first, just select the window and press the delete key. For the seconds, add the key `LSUIElement` and set it to be a boolean True